# Authenticated Referrals Not Displaying

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-authentication

I am stuck trying to use the authenticated referrals section in the Auth Dialog section of the app developer. I have setup setup my app, and I have some code to login, and perform some checks, but whenever the authorize app screen appears, the data I entered into the Authenticated Referrals Section is never shown, I only see the "The App will receive: Your basic data."

I have tried disabling and re-enabling the Enhanced Auth Dialog under the Advanced section of the app, have tried clearing my cache, and even resetting my secret key. I've browsed plenty of sites/forums, but haven't found any solution. What am I missing?

Any suggestions would be great

Comment: Basically, what I am seeing when prompted to give the app permission to my page is what is displayed when clicking the 'Preview Current Dialog' link, not what I see when I click the 'Preview Referral Dialog' link. The latter is what I expect to see when prompted to give the app permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the auth dialogs you're seeing are actually Authenticated Referral dialogs?

If you navigate to your app manually that's not an authenticated referral and your code needs to manually call the auth dialog - Authenticated Referrals appear when users click links to your app from requests, news feed stories, etc. - more info is [in the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals)

If users are landing on your app and you're not directing them to the correct set of permissions in the auth dialog - see the [Authentication docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) to see how to proceed - basically you redirect them to the Auth dialog, with a `scope` parameter containing the permissions you need, then complete the auth flow when they come back to your app (how you do this depends on which SDK you use)

Comment: That was what the problem was, but is there any other way to generate this type of authorization/login without going through a facebook link. a.k.a. something directly from my site?

Comment: Yes, look at the authentication docs and the Auth dialog - you can link users directly to the Oauth dialog and provided the redirect_uri parameter is owned by your app (i.e. is on your server) they'll be brought into the app after clicking allow