# Difference between Current Dialog and Referral Dialog

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

Folks:
      I am new to Facebook Development. I have a problem showing which user details my app is asking for in the Auth Dialog. It always show a user that the app will receive his basic info. On the app settings page at Apps-->AppName--> Auth Dialog I can see 2 preview dialogs. One is Current dialog, this is what user sees, and a referral dialog, this is what I want to display to user but I am unable to show it. My question is whats the difference between the 2 dialogs and how can I enable the refferal dialog to be shown always.

I want to achieve a login dialog like the one in the below site

http://www.trippy.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authenticated Referrals Not Displaying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455142/authenticated-referrals-not-displaying)

Answer (score 0):

Mark - the referral dialogue is when a link created and posted by an app user is clicked on by a non-app user in the news feed, ticker, etc.  You can read the exact details here, does a much better job at explaining than I do.  :)  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals